# How to display the current date in ms since epoch in PHP?

Tags: php, date, milliseconds

I would like to display today's date as the number of ms since epoch

I know that I can use

```
microtime(true) / 1000
```

to so so, but I would like to strip the hour, minutes, ms from this result.
I would like to get 2016/01/28 00:00:00 in ms. Of course this is an example, as I want the date to be the current day.
Any idea on how to do so in PHP ?

Comment: Actually it should be `microtime(true) * 1000`.

Comment: not if I want the result in ms as microtime returns the time in µs

Comment: No, `microtime(true)` returns the time in seconds, but as a float accurate to microseconds. From php.net: > If get_as_float is set to TRUE, then microtime() returns a float, which represents the current time in seconds since the Unix epoch accurate to the nearest microsecond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply

```
echo sprintf('%d',strtotime('midnight'));



$midnight_lastnight=strtotime('midnight - 24hours');
$midnight_tonight=strtotime('midnight');
$midnight_tomorrow=strtotime('midnight + 24hours');

echo '<pre>';
echo $midnight_lastnight.' '.date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $midnight_lastnight );
echo $midnight_tonight.' '.date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $midnight_tonight );
echo $midnight_tomorrow.' '.date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $midnight_tomorrow );
echo '</pre>';

outputs:
--------
1453852800 2016-01-27 00:00:00
1453939200 2016-01-28 00:00:00
1454025600 2016-01-29 00:00:00
```

Comment: $midnight_tonight=strtotime('midnight'); 
was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you mean, but if you just want to show the number of milliseconds of the current time, `microtime(true) * 1000 % 1000` would work.

Comment: This isn't what I'm asking, because this will just display 'now' in ms.
I want to display the current date at 00:00:00 in ms

Comment: I want 2016/01/28 00:00:00  in ms where the date will change everyday

Comment: So the input is `2016/01/28 00:00:00`, and the output is the number of milliseconds from epoch to 2016/01/28 00:00:00?